# Data.Table: Aggregate by every two weeks

Tags: r, data.table

So let's take the following data.table. It has dates and a column of numbers. I'd like to get the week of each date and then aggregate (sum) of each two weeks.

```
Date <- as.Date(c("1980-01-01", "1980-01-02", "1981-01-05", "1981-01-05", "1982-01-08", "1982-01-15", "1980-01-16", "1980-01-17", 
                  "1981-01-18", "1981-01-22", "1982-01-24", "1982-01-26"))
Runoff <- c(2, 1, 0.1, 3, 2, 5, 1.5, 0.5, 0.3, 2, 1.5, 4)
DT <- data.table(Date, Runoff)
DT
```

So from the date, I can easily get the year and week.

```
DT[,c("Date_YrWeek") := paste(substr(Date,1,4), week(Date), sep="-")][]
```

What I'm struggling with is aggregating with every two week.
I thought that I'd get the first date for each week and filter using those values. Unfortunately, that would be pretty foolish.

```
DT[,.(min(Date)),by=.(Date_YrWeek)][order(Date)]
```

The final result would end up being the sum of every two weeks.

```
weeks    sum_value
1 and 2  ...
3 and 4  ...
5 and 6  ...
```

Anyone have an efficient way to do this with data.table?

Answer (score 5):

**1)** Define the two week periods as starting from the minimum Date.  Then we can get the total Runoff for each such period like this.

```
DT[, .(sum_value = sum(Runoff)), 
     keyby = .(Date = 14 * (as.numeric(Date - min(Date)) %/% 14) + min(Date))]
```

giving the following where the Date column is the date of the first day of the two week period.

```
         Date sum_value
1: 1980-01-01       3.0
2: 1980-01-15       2.0
3: 1980-12-30       3.1
4: 1981-01-13       2.3
5: 1981-12-29       2.0
6: 1982-01-12       6.5
7: 1982-01-26       4.0
```

**2)** If you prefer the text shown in the question for the first column then:

```
DT[, .(sum_value = sum(Runoff)), 
    keyby = .(two_week = as.numeric(Date - min(Date)) %/% 14)][
    , .(weeks = paste(2*two_week + 1, "and", 2*two_week + 2), sum_value)]
```

giving:

```
         weeks sum_value
1:     1 and 2       3.0
2:     3 and 4       2.0
3:   53 and 54       3.1
4:   55 and 56       2.3
5: 105 and 106       2.0
6: 107 and 108       6.5
7: 109 and 110       4.0
```

**Update:** Revised and added (2).

Answer (score 4):

With tidyverse and lubridate:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

summary <- DT %>% 
              mutate(TwoWeeks = round_date(Date, "2 weeks")) %>%
              group_by(TwoWeeks) %>%
              summarise(sum_value = sum(Runoff))
summary
# A tibble: 9 × 2
    TwoWeeks sum_value
      <date>     <dbl>
1 1979-12-30       3.0
2 1980-01-13       1.5
3 1980-01-20       0.5
4 1981-01-04       3.1
5 1981-01-18       0.3
6 1981-01-25       2.0
7 1982-01-10       2.0
8 1982-01-17       5.0
9 1982-01-24       5.5
```

Lubridate's round_date() will aggregate dates within ranges you can specify through size and unit, in this case, "2 weeks". round_date()'s output is the first calendar day of that period.

Comment: `lubridate::round_date(..., "2 weeks")` warns with `Multi-unit not supported for weeks` and does not do what is needed. And since *this* answer shows weekly instead of biweekly, it appears that either the warning was suppressed, the package used here was at least a year old (https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/commit/c058038337b328c5df08840b5ffb5d7a0f76778d), or something else. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65688058/3358272 for alternatives.